# No Job Contol Error

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying to use % host or % dig in script file. To extract source code of a website. 
For example:

```
% host askubuntu.com
```

But I execute file I get this error:

```
fg: no job control
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to be definitive without the context of what you're trying to do, however it is likely that you are copying commands from a book or website that uses `%` to indicate the shell prompt - it is not part of the command, and you are not meant to type it. The commands should probably just be

```
host askubuntu.com
```

or

```
dig askubuntu.com
```

You're getting the error because `%` has a special meaning in the bash shell, where `%n` used to bring the nth backgrounded process into the foreground. Specifically, you're getting `fg: no job control` because job control is disabled by default in non-interactive shells.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new and didn't know that. Thank you!